# jQuery autocomplete loop through values of selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin like below. This works fine, but I'd like to loop through the values of the selected item. For example, if 'Product 1' were selected, I'd like to log this to the console:

```
label : Product 1
value : value1
tax   : 18%
```

I just cannot figure how to do this. If I do `console.log(ui)` I can see the values, but how do I loop through them? Can you please help?

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">choices ...</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="choice" name="choice" id="choice">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">value of choices ...</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="prid" id="prid">
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#choice").autocomplete({
    source: [{
        label: "Product 1",
        value: "value1",
        tax: "18%"
      },
      // These aren't fixed. Some products have, some less.
      {
        label: "Product 2",
        value: "value2",
        tax: "24%"
      }
    ],
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#choice').val(ui.item.label);
      this.value = ui.item.label;
      $('#prid').val(ui.item.tax);
      // I'm stuck over here
      for (var i = 0; i < ui.length; i++) {
        console.log(ui[i]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. `ui.item` refers to the **single** object in the array relating to the option selected in the UI. As such there is nothing to loop over. You just access the properties as you already are in the preceding lines of code.

Comment: If you do console.log(ui) you'll get (index):55 {item: {…}}item: {label: "Microsoft Windows 10", value: "MS WIN10", tax: "18%"}__proto__: Object. I'm trying to loop through that.

Comment: That's my point. It's a single object. There is nothing to loop through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ui` contains the following object

```
{
  "item": {
    "label": "Product 1",
    "value": "value1",
    "tax": "18%"
  }
}
```

If you want to loop over the keys then you use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
var uiEntries = Object.entries(ui.item)
for (var i = 0; i < uiEntries.length; i++) {
    var uiEntry = uiEntries[i];
    //uiEntry[0] = The key
    //uiEntry[1] = The value
    console.log(uiEntry[0] + ":", uiEntry[1]);
}
```

Alternatively, just log all the known keys, you will then get `undefined` for any value that doesn't exist

```
console.log("label : ", ui.item.label);
console.log("value : ", ui.item.value);
console.log("tax : ", ui.item.tax);
```

Comment: I'm getting `(index):56 Uncaught TypeError: Object.Entries is not a function`...

Comment: It was a typo, it should be lower case `Object.entries()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries